# Is there a formula to determine equivalent units after an exchange rate?

Tags: finance

The easiest example is money. Let's say I have `$100 USD`, and I want to convert part of this money to `CAD`, at an exchange rate of `1.3`. I want to have the *same* quantity of USD as CAD at the end of the process.

If you do rough napkin math for the `$100 USD` example above, the exchanged amount would be roughly `43.55`. This leaves `56.45` USD, and results in `56.62` CAD.

Are there any formulas or functions that can determine the `43.55` amount?

Comment: $$\begin{cases}x+y&=100\\x-1.3y&=0\end{cases}\implies (x,y)=\left(\frac{1300}{23},\frac{1000}{23}\right)\approx(56.522,43.478)$$

Comment: Where does the `23` come from in that formula @PeterForeman?

Comment: See my answer below for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will generalise the statement made in my comment. Suppose we have $z$ monetary units of type"$A$". We can split this into two parts - the part which is not exchanged and the part which is. Call these parts $x$ and $y$. We trivially have $x+y=z$ as the two parts should add to give the entire sum of money. If the exchange rate is $k$ monetary units of type "$B$" per unit of type "$A$" then we want the resulting exchanged amount $(ky)$ to be equal to the non-exchanged amount $(x)$. This is equivalent to $x=ky$ or $x-ky=0$. This system of equations can then be solved by various methods to give
$$\begin{cases}x+y&=z\\x-ky&=0\end{cases}\iff(x,y)=\left(\frac{kz}{k+1},\frac{z}{k+1}\right)$$
in which case the exchanged amount is $z/(k+1)$. So, in your example, the exchanged amount is $100/(1.3+1)=1000/23\approx43.478$.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you just solve a system of 2 linear equations in 2 unknowns.

The best way to think about this is to systematically translate "pieces of information I need" into "unknowns", and "pieces of information I have" into "equations".

The pieces of information you need are $x =$ final amount of USD and $y =$ final amount of CAD.

The pieces of information you have are (1) the final amount of USD equals the final amount of CAD, and (2) the exchanged amount (or $100 minus the final amount) of USD times the exchange rate equals the final amount CAD.

So your equations can be
$$
\begin{align}
  x &= y  \\
  1.3(100 - x) &= y
\end{align}
$$
You can eliminate $y$ right away and set $x = 1.3(100 - x)$. Solve:
$$
\begin{align}
  x &= 1.3(100 - x)  \\
  x &= 130 - 1.3x  \\
  2.3x &= 130  \\
  x &= 130 / 2.3  \\
  x &\approx 56.521739  \\
  100-x &\approx 43.478261
\end{align}
$$
So you can exchange USD ~43.48 to end up with USD ~56.52 and CAD ~56.52.